# Whats the Magento API for?

Tags: magento

I plan to use Magento next year so I started browsing the Magento website. I noticed the Magento Core API and wonder what it is for? Is it something I can use to integrate parts form a running Magento installation into other applications?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use it to push some information in and out of Magento using SOAP XML.